# Installing wordpress on my own server at the root

Tags: wordpress, installation

I am a little confused. I have wordpress on my server @ www.something.com/wordpress but what I really want to happen is when you visit www.something.com wordpress is at the root not a subfolder. Does this make sense. I have already installed wordpress do I have to reinstall it now delete this one and install it in the correct location.

Comment: Voting to close, as it's off-topic. Belongs to webmasters.stackexchange.com

Comment: I see what I did, I was supposed to add the contents of the wordpress folder not the folder itself into the root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you dont have shell access, the best route is to delete, and reinstall at the root, if you are using fantastico, or some tool to install it, when they ask you for the folder just type / and that will solve your problem.